# How to configure iRedMail with my dynamic Broadband IP?

Tags: ip, dynamic, email-server

I have Broadband connection in my small office with dynamic ip address.

I want to be able to configure iRedMail with POP & SMTP.

How am I able to configure the POP accounts and SMTP relay.

Comment: We need more information like providers / Router etc. But in short get a fixed IP.

Answer (score 2):

A dynamic IP will give you lots of problems on the SMTP front, because you will be unable to set up proper RDNS records, SPF and other pieces of proof that many mail servers now require to prove that you are an actual legitimate server, and not someone malicious.

If you set up an account with a DDNS provider, they can set up a domain that will follow your IP, and that will be acceptable for POP3 usage, but to send mail, you may want to configure your server to relay through someone with a fixed IP (your ISP's mail server for example).

If you want to do things properly, you'll need to obtain a static IP, otherwise, you'll be in for a lot of frustration.

Comment: I setup a static IP for my business a couple of months ago and actually ended up saving around $200 in the process. It turned out Shaw had a 1-year promo that works out cheaper than what I was paying for my residential internet service. Call your ISP and see if they can offer you any deals on your first year if you upgrade to a business internet package with a static IP.